# Smooth scrolling not working in Rails unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

We converted a page in our application that previously rendered content from various pages into a single page that smoothly scrolls to each section using Javascript.

The function does not work unless the page is refreshed. I believe it has to do with turbolinks cacheing the page.

Transition cacheing is enabled throughout

```
Turbolinks.enableTransitionCache()
```

The smooth scroll function

```
$(function() {
  $('.scroll-button').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 160
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried opting out of turbolinks and transition cacheing in various ways, most recently by tagging each link, the page container, and target section with `data-no-turbolink="true"`

Each link in `example_links.html.slim` has been tagged
    li 
      = link_to 'INFO', path, class: 'tab-link scroll-button', 'data-no-turbolink'=>'true'

The `show.html.slim` has the page container tagged

```
.row data-no-transition-cache="true" data-no-turbolink="true"
```

And each section targeted on that page is tagged

```
p.section-heading#someLabel data-no-turbolink="true"
```

How can I ensure that when the page is visited, either by clicking a link or using the back button, that the smooth scrolling function is enforced?

Answer (score 3):

Turbolinks emits events that allow you to track the navigation lifecycle and respond to page loading.

Replace

```
$(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
```

The former is shorthand for a event listener which is executed when the DOM is fully loaded. That event is not emitted when turbolinks renders a page (except for the when hitting a hard refresh. ie by pressing F5).

For more information about turbolinks event see https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events

Answer (score 0):

If Turbolinks is enabled (i.e. you've included turbolinks.js), javascript events like `$('.scroll-button').click(...)` need to be rewritten like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.scroll-button', function() {
  ...
});
```

Turbolinks changes your app's behavior to load your javascript only once and changes the `<body>` when loading new pages. As a result, events should be attached to `$(document)`, which doesn't change between page loads